# MariaDB: Using PK for inner query result

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, subquery, query-optimization

I have three tables (MariaDB 10.6.5): *person*, *private_person* and *corporate_person*. In the *person* are Ids stored, in the other tables are names stored, both connected to the *person* per FK:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `person` (
    `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TypeOfPerson` ENUM('PRIVATE','CORPORATE') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `private_person` (
    `PersonId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LastName` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`),
    INDEX `IX_private_person_FirstName` (`FirstName`),
    INDEX `IX_private_person_LastName` (`LastName`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_private_person_person_PersonId` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonId`) REFERENCES `person` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `corporate_person` (
    `PersonId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`),
    INDEX `IX_corporate_person_Name` (`Name`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_corporate_person_person_PersonId` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonId`) REFERENCES `person` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now I have to search for a name in both tables *private_person* and *corporate_person*:

```sql
SELECT `p`.Id
  FROM `test`.`person` AS `p`
  LEFT JOIN `test`.`private_person` AS `p0` ON `p`.`Id` = `p0`.`PersonId`
  LEFT JOIN `test`.`corporate_person` AS `c0` ON `p`.`Id` = `c0`.`PersonId`
  WHERE `p0`.`FirstName` = 'Test' OR p0.LastName = 'Test' OR `c0`.`Name` = 'Test';
```

But the query is a little slow because there are many rows in *person*:
[image]

so that I changed the query in:

```sql
SELECT Id FROM `test`.`person` WHERE Id IN (
SELECT p.Id
  FROM `test`.`person` AS `p`
  INNER JOIN `test`.`private_person` AS `p0` ON `p`.`Id` = `p0`.`PersonId`
  WHERE `p0`.`FirstName` = 'Test' OR `p0`.`LastName` = 'Test'
UNION SELECT p.Id
  FROM `test`.`person` AS `p`
  INNER JOIN `test`.`corporate_person` AS `c0` ON `p`.`Id` = `c0`.`PersonId`
  WHERE `c0`.`Name` = 'Test' ORDER BY Id);
```

The inner query (UNION) is quite fast, but, however, the whole statement is slow too:
[image]

And I do not understand why. The inner query gives only an amount of Ids, and why the optimizer doesn't use the primary index for these simple amount of Ids? When I give the Ids instead of the inner query

```sql
SELECT Id FROM `test`.`person` WHERE Id IN (25251, 47413, 99851 ...);
```

the statement is fast as well of course:
[image]

Even If I force the using of the primary index (`SELECT Id FROM test.person FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE ...`) it doesn't change anything; according to the query optimizer the primary index is used now, but the statement is not faster:
[image]

Why doesn't the optimizer use the primary index in a fast(er) way, if it gets only an amount of Ids from a subquery?

**EDIT:**
Sorry for some misunderstanding. I don't want to make the query faster, actually I had a solution for my concrete problem (the slow query in a more complex scenario than here described) before, maybe I missed to write this more explicitly. But during the development of a statement I try to use my knowledge about mysql and the optimizer, and here I was very surprised, I don't understand, where the problem is for mariadb. Again, the OUTER statement gets only a set of ids, and can't use the PK in proper way. In `SELECT Id FROM tabA WHERE Id IN (123, 456, 789)` the PK is used and the query is very fast, but `SELECT Id FROM tabA WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM tabB WHERE ...)` the PK is not used in a proper way, the optimizer crawls through the whole table *tabA*. Why is it? That's the question I tried to ask.

Comment: Since "persons" all have "names", move `name` to the common table!

Comment: It's not my table, I can't change the structures.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `OR` operations that doom your query.

```
  WHERE `p0`.`FirstName` = 'Test' OR p0.LastName = 'Test' OR `c0`.`Name` = 'Test';
```

This is a common problem with query optimization, given that MySQL uses only one index per table reference (even though [index merge optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) exists, it doesn't kick in as often as you'd think).

The problem is that the optimizer can't use a single B-tree index to look up several different columns like this.

The analogy I often use is to a telephone book. If you want to look up a person by last name, the order of the telephone book helps you do it efficiently, because it's alphabetized by last name first. But if you want to look up a person by their first name, the book doesn't help, because entries are not sorted by first name. If you want to look up a person by last name *or* first name, you still have to scan the whole book to find those who match by first name.

Suppose you had a second telephone book that is sorted by first name. That would help, but if you were constrained by a rule that forced you to search using only one book or the other, not both, then you'd be stuck. Whichever book you picked, you'd have to scan the whole book to search for the other name.

This is what happens when the optimizer only allows one index per table reference and you have `OR` conditions in your query.

A workaround that many people use is to do several queries and `UNION` their results.

```
SELECT `p`.Id
FROM `test`.`person` AS `p`
INNER JOIN `test`.`private_person` AS `p0` ON `p`.`Id` = `p0`.`PersonId`
WHERE `p0`.`FirstName` = 'Test'
UNION
SELECT `p`.Id
FROM `test`.`person` AS `p`
INNER JOIN `test`.`private_person` AS `p0` ON `p`.`Id` = `p0`.`PersonId`
WHERE p0.LastName = 'Test'
UNION
SELECT `p`.Id
FROM `test`.`person` AS `p`
INNER JOIN `test`.`corporate_person` AS `c0` ON `p`.`Id` = `c0`.`PersonId`
WHERE `c0`.`Name` = 'Test';
```

In this case, each table reference can use a different index, and search for the name you want more efficiently. Once it finds the small set of matching rows, they join back to the `person` table by that table's primary key (MySQL knows how to access tables in a different order than you list them in your query, so don't worry about which table is named first in your joins).

---

Re your comment:

Sometimes the optimizer makes some strange decisions about how to order the tables, based on its cost estimation model for which table would be better to access first. You can override it like this:

```
SELECT `p`.Id
FROM `private_person` AS `p0` 
STRAIGHT_JOIN `person` AS `p` ON `p`.`Id` = `p0`.`PersonId`
WHERE `p0`.`FirstName` = 'Test'
UNION
SELECT `p`.Id
FROM `private_person` AS `p0`
STRAIGHT_JOIN `person` AS `p` ON `p`.`Id` = `p0`.`PersonId`
WHERE p0.LastName = 'Test'
UNION
SELECT `p`.Id
FROM `corporate_person` AS `c0` 
STRAIGHT_JOIN `person` AS `p` ON `p`.`Id` = `c0`.`PersonId`
WHERE `c0`.`Name` = 'Test';
```

The `STRAIGHT_JOIN` means to use the table order as it appears in the SQL query.

With this, I tested the EXPLAIN output and got this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: p0
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IX_private_person_FirstName
          key: IX_private_person_FirstName
      key_len: 1023
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: test2.p0.PersonId
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: UNION
        table: p0
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IX_private_person_LastName
          key: IX_private_person_LastName
      key_len: 1023
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: UNION
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: test2.p0.PersonId
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: UNION
        table: c0
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IX_corporate_person_Name
          key: IX_corporate_person_Name
      key_len: 1023
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: UNION
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: test2.c0.PersonId
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: NULL
  select_type: UNION RESULT
        table: <union1,2,3>
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
     filtered: NULL
        Extra: Using temporary
```

This looks like it will use indexes better, and access the tables in the better order.

With the caveat that I just tested with empty tables, and that sometimes makes the optimizer confused about how to calculate the cost. Give it a try in your environment.

Comment: Hi Bill, thx for the explanation! But you explained, why the first statement is slow, but I would like to know, why is the changed statement slow too? There is a UNION, and the INNER subquery is very fast. You can see it in the (second) query plan. Only the outer statement 'person' makes the query so slow, but why? This outer statement gets only Ids from the inner statement, made for the PK. Why crawl the whole table for a set of ids, stored in the PK?

Comment: Bill, thank you for your great explanation again! You are right, your query is very fast like expected, and I have learned something new, didn't hear about `STRAIGHT_JOIN` before. Thank you! But, please see my EDIT above.

Answer (score 0):

In your Union case, `SELECT Id FROM` test`.`person `WHERE Id IN` is unnecessary.  It may be causing the inefficiency.

If you need more than simply `Id` from the result, try this instead:

```
SELECT ...  -- (more than just Id)
    FROM  ( (SELECT ...)
            UNION ALL
            (SELECT ...)
          ) AS x;
```

That essentially forces it to do the Union before thinking about the outer Select.

Note:  `UNION ALL` can cause dups (depending on the details) but is faster than `UNION` (which means `UNION DISTINCT`).  That is, if you know that there are no dups, tack on `ALL`.